# Meaning of volitional passive form

Tags: grammar, particle-が, passive-voice, volitional-form

> お姉ちゃんに何を**言われようが**、まる子はウキウキ気分なのであった。
>   What was said by her sister ???? but, Maruko felt cheerful.

I can't think of any way in which something which is passive can also be volitional. How do I understand this construction?

Comment: ～ようが is similar to ～ても.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「何, どこ, だれ, いつ etc. + ～～(よ)うが」
「何, どこ, だれ, いつ etc. + ～～(よ)うと(も)」
「何, どこ, だれ, いつ etc. + ～～ても」
mean "No matter what, where, who, etc. ~~". For example:

> 何を言お**うが** / 何を言お**うと**(**も**) / 何を言っ**ても**
>   (No matter what ~~ say, ...)
>   どこに行こ**うが** / どこに行こ**うと**(**も**) / どこに行っ**ても**
>   (No matter where ~~ go, ...)
>   何があろ**うが** / 何があろ**うと**(**も**) / 何があっ**ても**
>   (No matter what happens, ...)
>   何を頼まれ**ようが** / 何を頼まれ**ようと**(**も**) / 何を頼まれ**ても**  ← passive + よう
>   (No matter what ~~ is requested)

The auxiliary verb よう has other meanings than volitional. I think the よう here is [#5 in デジタル大辞泉](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/226119/meaning/m0u/): 「仮定の意を表す。」(expresses a hypothetical/conditional meaning).

So your example:

> お姉ちゃんに何を言われようが、まる子はウキウキ気分なのであった。

is like 「お姉ちゃんに何を言われようと(も)～」, 「お姉ちゃんに何を言われても～」, (Lit.) "No matter what Maruko was told by her sister, ~~" -> "No matter what her sister said to her, Maruko was feeling just so excited / exhilarated."

Answer (score 2):

I found another example with this form:

> ここから出ていく何と言われようとも！
>
> So I'm getting out of here, whatever anybody says!

So I guess the translation of your sentence is

> Whatever her sister said, Maruko felt cheerful.