# What does this sentence mean? I can't understand this 求められようと

Tags: translation, meaning

> 説明を**求められようと**、何も言えないのだ。

What does it mean? "Trying to be asked for answers, I can't say anything" looks strange...

Comment: This thread might be of some help: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/32949/meaning-of-volitional-passive-form/32959#32959 求められようと(も)≂求められたとしても≂求められようが

Answer (score 2):

> 説明を求められようと、何も言えないのだ。
>   **Even if** [you] demand an explanation, [I] can not say anything.

`volitional-form + が/と` is a literary way of saying "even if ～" or "regardless of ～". Usually (but not always) there is a comma after the が/と.

Examples on JGram:

- [(よ)うが (よ)うと ようが ようと](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=(yo)uga%2C(yo)uto)
- [(よ)うと～まい, (よ)うが～まい](http://www.jgram.org/pages/viewOne.php?tagE=(yo)uto~mai%2C%20(yo)uga~mai)

Of course `volitional-form + と` can be actual volition followed by a quotative particle, depending on what follows:

> 説明を求めようと思います。
>   I think I will demand an explanation.

Comment: In case OP is wondering why を is used after 説明, here's [why](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/11025/5010).

Answer (score 0):

There is a great page :

> [japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar -you-nimonai](http://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n1-grammar-%EF%BC%88%E3%82%88%EF%BC%89%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-you-nimonai/)
> Meaning: even if one tries to do something, it can’t be done
>
> ジェイクを呼ぼうにも声が出なかった。
> I tried to call Jake, but my voice was gone.

[ 呼ぼうにも] -- This part feels like the subjunctive of European languages.

- Were I to call Jake ...
- Even if I were to call Jake ...
- Even if I would want to call Jake ...
- Even if I would've wanted to call Jake ...　Try as I might to call Jake ...

When the [1st person] is trying, it's ～しようにも

When the [Another party] is trying/asking, it's ～しようと, ～しようとも, etc. (See Choco-san's link).

> e.g. -- どんなに激しく雨が降ろうと、この家の屋根は大丈夫だ。

Comment: But... the OP's sentence cannot be rephrased 「求められよう**に**も」... and your sentence (「呼ぼうにも」≂「呼ぼうとしても」) cannot be rephrased 「呼ぼう**と**も」...

Answer (score 0):

求められる means sought, (gave) order, request, recommend...
〜ようと means "but".   It same as 〜だが, 〜が, 〜ても.
In English, That sentence:

> It gave order to explain, but I cannot say nothing.

Comment: The translation is (roughly) correct, but 〜ても doesn't appear in the question.