# I need help to understand this sentence: おじいさんはないをやらせてもだめなんだもの

Tags: meaning, sentence

I'm a totally newbie in learning Japanese and I'm struggling to understand that sentence:

> おじいさんはないをやらせてもだめなんだもの。

I know おじいさん is "grandfather" and it seems like はない means "is not present", but if so I don't understand the role of the particle を.

The following part is quite dark to me: maybe だもの could indicate a reason, but I'm not sure about it.

Thank you.

Comment: な**い**をやらせても <- You sure you've copied it correctly? It should be な**に**をやらせても.

Comment: Welcome to JLSE. You've shown your research effort, so I voted to reopen this question. Meanwhile, as Chocolated pointed out, this ないを is clearly a typo for なにを. Does this help you understand the sentence more?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This ない is clearly a typo for なに.

> おじいさんは**なに**をやらせてもだめなんだもの。
>
> - Grandpa is no-good whatever we have him to do.
> - I can't get my grandpa to do anything!

- **おじいさんは**: You got this part right. "as for Grandpa"
- **なにをやらせても**: やらせる is the causative-form of やる, or "make/let him do". を simply marks the object of やる. "何/どこ/誰 + ても" is a grammar pattern that means "whatever" etc. See: [Meaning of volitional passive form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32949/5010) / [Maggie Sensei: Wh-ever/No matter wh/how: ても/でも ( = temo/demo)](http://maggiesensei.com/2016/10/12/wh-everno-matter-whhow-%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82-temodemo/)
- **だめなんだ**: だめ means "no good", "useless", etc.
- **もの**: もの is a little old-fashioned sentence-end particle used to present a reason and convince someone. See: [〜ものだから　〜もの　～もん What are the differences?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5648/5010) / [JLPT N2 Grammar もの/もん](https://jlptsensei.com/learn-japanese-grammar/%E3%82%82%E3%81%AE-mono-%E3%82%82%E3%82%93-mon-meaning/)

Comment: Thank you, your explanation is very clear!